# How I short out this error Resource Exhausted Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I created a model with 13500 images. During the training time after 1 epoch showing an ERROR: "ResourceExhaustedError".[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEWLX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YJxV.png)

My system Ryzen7 AMD  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650/120Hz

Image Classification using Tensorflow with Keras.

I enclose MY LAYER below

```
overall_model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = "relu", input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size = (3,3),activation= "relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size = (3,3),activation= "relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(len(class_names),activation='softmax')

])
```

Batch size = 16
epochs = 5

Thanking you

Help to solve my error.
If I need any corrections or changes in my model let me know...

Comment: 13500 images of what size?

Comment: Image size 256x256 and Storage is 150Mb

Comment: Have you done the math?  13500 color images of size 256x256 requires 3 gigabytes.